# What's the "atomic disk write" for a Linux filesystem?

Tags: linux, http, nginx, filesystems

From the nginx config file readme:

> access_log:
>
> An optional third parameter indicates the size of the buffer
>
> If write buffering is used, this size cannot exceed the size of the atomic disk write for that filesystem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This actually depends on the filesystem being used. This is probably referring to the stat.blksize filesystem attribute.

From the [stat(2)](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman2/stat.2.html) manual page:

```
       struct stat {

           /* ... */

           blksize_t st_blksize;     /* blocksize for filesystem I/O */
```

The -f option to the [stat(1)](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman1/stat.1.html) appears to display this information, and on my Linux box, it shows 4096 as the block size.

Comment: @styfle - it has to be bytes, i.e. 4kb. Having a 4 megabyte physical block size would be quite hilarious.